# How to authenticate internal corporate proxy with credentials in order to reach external API

Tags: python, macos, proxy, kerberos

We have a requirement in consuming an external API, in order to reach to their endpoint, we would need to authenticate our proxy first.

How can we achieve this using python, seems like there is one in

```
c# ---> CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
```

How to do it in python,

so far I have tried:

```
import requests

proxies = {"https":"https://url:port/file"}
client_cert = ("key/path", "cert/path")
data = """xml request"""
requests.post(url, proxy=proxy, data=data, cert=client_cert)
```

I have read in the docs saying there is http digest authentication like 
I can use https://username:password@url:port/file .

Any suggestions?

> ERROR:
>
> HTTPSConnectionPool, failed to establish connection

Answer (score 0):

Actually, My question has answer:

```
proxy = {"http": "http://username:password@proxy:port", "https":"http://username:password@proxy:port"}

requests.post(url, headers, auth, cert, payload, proxies=proxy) #===> works

or else we can set the environment variable.
export https_proxy = "http://username:password@proxy:port"
export http_proxy = "http://username:password@proxy:port"
```

In my case there were multiple proxies for our company and I was using the incorrect proxy details. When I tried with an accurate one. It worked.
Thanks to Stack